# Get response from asynchronous web service in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

With this code, the result returned by the method EndcreateUser is always null:

```
ServiceReference1.CustomerClient c = new CustomerClient(); 
IAsyncResult asyncResult = c.BegincreateUser(
    WebApplication1.ServiceReference1.Credential credential, 
    WebApplication1.ServiceReference1.User user, 
    int accountType, 
    **System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState**); 
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); 
UserCreateResult userResult = c.EndcreateUser(asyncResult);
```

When I try to send XML with other method, it's work, but it's not useful because I have to create all of the XML code myself:

```
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = p_xmlDocument;
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

// begin async call to web request.
IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

// suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
// do something usefull here like update your UI.
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

// get the response from the completed web request.
string soapResult;
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I don't know why, do you have an idea?

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing the definitions of your service but is this line:  `...c.BegincreateUser(WebApplication1.ServiceReference1.Credential credential, WebApplication1.ServiceReference1.User user, int accountType, **System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState**);` working at all?

Comment: yes it's work fine but userResult returns by EndcreateUser() is null, I need this response to check if user is created and save data which are in userResult object

Comment: Why are you calling the webservice asynchronously if you're not going to be doing anything between your call and its callback?
You might as well use the synchronous method on the client object.